# How to make an ajax request such that it is processed as JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, get, request

I'm doing a vanilla javascript ajax request (hence not using jQuery) with the following code:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", my_path, false);
xhReq.send(null);
var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
```

But my server app (Rails) is handling it as a HTML request:

```
Processing by CommunitiesController#show as HTML
```

**How can I do the ajax request such that it is processed as JS?**

Comment: Does `my_path` return pure JavaScript, or JS wrapped in HTML?

Comment: It will return pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to your path .js OR send an extra param to indicate that its a js request {format=> "js"}